# SP2013 Document Library: multiple value lookup and group by based on the values selected

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, grouping, multiple-values

SP2013 environment here.

I have a document library that will need to have Manufacture Column (A,B,C .. etc) and a Model Column (Based on Manufacture Column), (like A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, etc)

The Model Column will need to be Multiple selection.
Then I would like a view GroupBy (Manufacture).

For example. Document1 with Model A1, B1 selected. It would appear under GroupBy Manufacture A and Manufacture B.

Is there anything I can do OOTB and not using any javacode (security policy issue).

Thanks for the big help!

Answer (score 0):

**In short,** the `Multiple selection` Choice field is **not** supported to be used as a `Group By` column in the `Group By setting`.

[image]

---

**Workaround**

- **Option 1:**     Display choices using:  `Drop-Down Menu` or `Radio Buttons`
- **Option 2:** Consider to merge the manufacture options, like `manufacture 1`, `manufacture 2` , `manufacture 1&2` ....etc and use one selection instead multiple!